# Printing select query result in text file in mapbasic

Tags: mapbasic

I want to print a select query having number of records in text file in mapbasic but no successful results as i am using below code:

```
Open file "E:\Export.txt" for output as #1
Print #1, select Col1, col2 from table1
close #1
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a loop to fetch the first row from the query and print it, before moving to the next row and then continuing until the end of the table - `EOT()` eg:

```
Select * From table1 Where ... Into my_query
Open file "E:\Export.txt" For Output As #1
Fetch First From my_query
Do While Not EOT(my_query)
    Write #1, my_query.col1, my_query.col2
    Fetch Next From my_query
Loop
Close File #1
```

The `Write #1` statement will automatically add commas between fields. If you don't want this then use `Print #1`. 
You might find it easier to export your query as a CSV file. If you manually export a table with the MapBasic window open you will see the syntax required.

Comment: When i run the code using your given suggestion, window appears that "Mapinfo@professional application file has stopped working". i have to close program.